# Is There a Built-in Method in TypeScript to Dynamically Resolve and Compile Internal Dependencies within a Monorepo for Publication?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a npm workspace (monorepo):

`package.json`:

```json
{
  "workspaces": [ "packages/*" ]
}
```

In `packages` I have 3 projects :

- `a` (`"name": "a"`)
- `b` (`"name": "b"`)
- `shared` (`"name": "@internal/shared"`)

Now `a` and `b` will have `@internal/shared` as a common dependency to avoid duplicating code.
For instance in `b/src/index.ts` I can type

```js
import {something} from '@internal/shared';
```

This is naturally resolved because `@internal/shared` is part of the monorepo (npm workspaces).

**However** as the name implies `@internal/shared` is internal and won't be published to npm, that also means I need to move the shared objects in `a` or `b` when I compile my code so when I publish `a` or `b` there are no dead references.

Ideally, assuming I have `"outDir": "lib"` in my ts config, when I compile:

```js
import {something} from '@internal/shared';
```

The output should ressemble something as the following

```js
import {something} from './@internal/shared/index.js';
```

and `lib` directory should contain both the current package compiled files and `./@internal/shared/**/*.js` used objects.

Does TypeScript have this feature built-in (or do I have to compile/move objects from my shared directory to the current package before build)?

Comment: What is the purpose? This would mean that your published code would have a dependency that others can't access, therefore others couldn't build your code, right? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @JSmart523 This is exactly the question I am asking, how to avoid having a dead dependency, is there a way to tell TypeScript to resolve an internal library during compilation? I want to be able to use *npm workspaces*, internal shared library and TS in the same monorepo.

Comment: Did you try project references and composite mode? Do the requirements of your project allow for bundling before publishing?

Comment: this question is underspecified: what do you want to happen when the internal shared dependency depends upon another (public) package that A and B have no direct dependency on? do you want that dependency to be copied to a public-facing package.json for A and B? do you want it to be inlined/bundled into A and B along with the internal shared dependency?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for a solution where TypeScript can automatically resolve and include the contents of an internal library (`@internal/shared`) into your projects (`a` and `b`) during compilation. That would eliminate the dependency on `@internal/shared` when the projects are published, as the required code would already be included in the compiled output.

[TypeScript's compiler](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) does not provide an out-of-the-box feature for automatically inlining or embedding dependencies from one package into another during compilation. TypeScript's role is primarily focused on type checking and transpiling TypeScript code to JavaScript, not on module resolution or dependency bundling for publication.

As commented, should the requirements of your project allow for bundling before publishing, you might consider bundling with [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/) or [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/): These tools can bundle your internal shared code directly into your output files. When configuring the bundler, you can specify how to handle internal packages like `@internal/shared`: the output for `a` and `b` will have the necessary code from `@internal/shared` baked in, removing the runtime dependency.
See, for illustration, "[Compiling and bundling TypeScript libraries with Webpack](https://marcobotto.com/blog/compiling-and-bundling-typescript-libraries-with-webpack/)" from [Marco Botto](https://marcobotto.com/about/).

By using a bundler like Webpack or Rollup, the shared code from `@internal/shared` is included directly in the bundles of `a` and `b`. That means that, when you publish `a` and `b`, they no longer have `@internal/shared` as an external dependency. The necessary code is already included in their respective bundles, thus eliminating any dead dependencies.

During the bundling process, these tools analyze your import statements (such as `import {something} from '@internal/shared';`) and include the referenced code directly in the output bundle. That process effectively resolves the internal library during the "compilation" step, although it is more accurate to say this resolution happens during the bundling step, which typically occurs *after* TypeScript compilation.

Bundling tools are generally compatible with [npm workspaces](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/workspaces) and TypeScript [monorepos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monorepo). They can be configured to recognize the structure of a monorepo and handle internal dependencies appropriately. The configuration will involve specifying the entry points for each package (`a` and `b`) and making sure that the bundler is aware of the internal paths to `@internal/shared`.

In development, you can continue using TypeScript and npm workspaces as usual. The bundling is an additional step that primarily comes into play when preparing your packages for publication.

Another approach would use custom build tools, like [Lerna](https://lerna.js.org/) or [Nx](https://nx.dev/getting-started/intro), which are designed for managing monorepos, might provide more sophisticated ways to handle such scenarios (with some configuration and custom scripting).
See, for illustration, "[Setting up a monorepo with Lerna for a TypeScript project](https://blog.logrocket.com/setting-up-monorepo-lerna-typescript/)" from [Vlado Tesanovic](https://github.com/vladotesanovic).

While TypeScript alone cannot fulfill your requirements, combining it with bundling tools or custom build scripts can achieve the desired outcome. The key is to make sure the compiled output of `a` and `b` includes the necessary code from `@internal/shared`, which would remove the runtime dependency.